# Was there a peak in suicides associated with the release of Pokémon red and green?

Tags: videogames, suicide

My 13-year-old stepson just told me this story: When [Pokémon Red and Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Red_and_Blue) was first released in 1996, there were dozens or hundreds of suicides of children caused by high-frequency sounds in the theme music for the "Lavender Town" location in the game.  The game developers had to change the music to prevent additional suicides.

Here are detailed descriptions of this story:

- http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/Lavender_Town_Syndrome
- http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/lavender-town-syndrome-creepypasta
- http://www.forums.711clan.net/showthread.php?t=10752

Is there any evidence that anything like this occurred, or that it could have occurred?

(I should note that I dismiss this story as false simply due to its implausibility and lack of credible sources, but my stepson is convinced it is true.  His friends who told him about it believe it, and it is discussed as if true in online gaming forums.  To him, the fact that major news organizations did not report it is evidence of a cover-up.  I'm hoping to use this opportunity to teach him something about critical thinking.)

Comment: obligatory correlation related [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/925/)

Comment: From the knowyourmeme link that you provided, it's stated that this came from 4chan, which is well known as being a source of trolling. Every time I've seen this urban legend it's always been quite clear that it's just that - an urban legend.

Comment: creepypastas are urban myth by definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_phenomena

Comment: Is this related to the "outbreak" of epileptic seizures caused by flashing graphics in one or more episodes of the show?  See [Photosensitive epilepsy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy).

Comment: The [exact same question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/how-true-is-the-lavender-town-syndrome) has been asked and answered over on SE's very own Anime and Manga site, and though it's not really answered to Skeptics standards it could serve as a jumping off point.

Comment: Wasn't Pokemon released as red and blue outside of Japan? It seems if the claim specifically mentions red and green, it is necessarily restricted to Japan.

Comment: Although, the same music is the same in Red and Blue and Green, but strange that the claim would mention Red and Green instead of the more international Red and Blue.

Comment: 'Associated with' or 'directly related to' is the real question here.